# Write table data read from word document into excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

My word document contains multiple tables.
I am able to read the tables data using Apache POI, but i am unable to write that data into excel workbook.

Code for reading word document:

```
        List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();

    System.out
            .println("==========No Of Tables in Document============================================="
                    + table.size());

    for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {

        System.out.println("================table -" + tableIdx
                + "===Data==");

        rowIdx = 1;
        List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
        ArrayList<String> rawData = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {



            colIdx = 1;
            List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();

            for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
                if (xwpfTableCell != null) {

                    aryNumbers[rowIdx][colIdx] = xwpfTableCell.getText()
                            .toString();


                }
                colIdx++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
            rowIdx++;
        }
        tableIdx++;
    }

}
```

For writing data into excel, i am using this code:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("StructureValidation");
    int rowCount = 0;

    for (Object[] aBook : aryNumbers) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

        int columnCount = 0;

        for (Object field : aBook) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
            if (field instanceof String) {

                cell.setCellValue((String) field);

            } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
            }
        }

    }
```

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("JavaBooks.xlsx")) {

            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
```

After reading data from thw word document i want to write it on the excel workbook.
But i am unable to do so , please help.

Comment: "Unable" in what way? Do you get errors? Do you get bad results? Please [edit] your question, add the relevant code, add stack traces if you have errors, and add the expected and actual results. A [mcve] will be best.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so post the program and stacktrace. If you need help in getting started here is the documentation from poi,                    https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html                                                  https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Comment: @RealSkeptic : i tried writing to excels sheet, i am not getting any errors , but my data is added in random order .
For ex- heading1 is written in col1, heading2 is written in col2.

Comment: @Santo - 
xwpfTableCell.getText()- this line gives me data read from word document , I want to write this data into excel in same table order as it was in word document,?I tried but i am unable to write data into excel sheet.

Comment: Your reading code doesn't create the array that your writing code uses. In fact, it doesn't seem to do anything with the data other than printing it. Please write a [mcve].

Comment: @RealSkeptic -yes , reading code is just reading the table data, i tried writing that data into excel, please see the question, i've updated the question ,

Comment: @mayankbisht Where is `aBook` coming from? how are you calling that write code? We still need a [mcve].

Comment: Guys i've updated the code..
Now i am able to added the data into excel, but now i am facing new problem .
First : I'm using array with fixed size to store values, which i know is a bad practice, so i tried  using Object[][] obName=null;, but that's giving NullPointException.

Second: Since my word document contains multiple table, one table itself contains many tables, so i want to write different table data to different data.